# Lua Error Attempt to perform arithmetic on local variable

Tags: lua, luajava

Here is the function 
calc.lua:

```
function foo(n) 
return n*2 
end
```

Here is my LuaJavaCall

```
L.getGlobal("foo");
L.pushJavaObject(8);
int retCode=L.pcall(1,1,0); // nResults)//L.pcall(1, 1,-2);
String errstr =  L.toString(-1);   // Attempt to perform arithmetic on local variable 'n'
```

Update: as indicated below I needed to use L.pushNumber(8.0) instead of L.pushJavaObject()

Comment: I'm not sure but could it have something to do with `L.pushJavaObject(8);`? What if you tried a `L.pushNumber(8);` instead?

Comment: do you want me to post that as an actual answer for you to accept in that case? ;)

Comment: yes, and please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621939/luajava-setting-error-handler-for-luastate-pcalla-b-error-function-index

Answer (score 1):

Try using `L.pushNumber` instead of `L.pushJavaObject` like this:

```
L.getGlobal("foo");
L.pushNumber(8.0);
int retCode = L.pcall(1,1,0);
String errstr = L.toString(-1);
```

Lua probably sees JavaObject as a type of 'userdata' in which case there are no predefined operations for it; Lua won't know what to do with a `JavaObject * 2` since you didn't define how to handle it.

OTOH, Lua does know how to handle a number since that's a builtin primitive type. For the code snippet you presented, pushing a number would be the least painful way to get it working instead of writing extra code that tells Lua how to work with numbers wrapped inside a JavaObject.